# class - tweet - 0 - to_do

Tags: php, php5

This class sends "tweet" data to the client in the form of a custom markup language.  How can it be improved?

It is used in Ajax call and in previous post people have suggested not to echo the result..but this is my primary means of communicating with the server via Ajax responseText.

Also `<tw_p>` is used to denote a pass and is read by the client.  The markup looks like this.

field 1 | field 2 | field 3 | field 4 || field 1 | field 2 | field 3 | field 4 ||

It is called like this -

```
new tweet();
```

The client knows how render this into xhtml once it receives it.

```
/*tweet*/

class tweet extends post
  {
  function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $email=$_SESSION['email'];
    $flname=$_SESSION['name'];
    $message=$this->_protected_arr['f4b'];
    $time=time();
    database::query("INSERT INTO tw VALUES ('$time','$flname','$message','$email')");        
    $query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7");
    $b=0;
    $c='<tw_p>';
    while($a=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
      {  
      if($b==0)
        {
        $c = $c . $a['email'] . "|" .  $a['fname'] . "|" . $a['time'] . "|" . $time . "|" . $a['message'];
        }
      else
        {
        $c = $c . "||" . $a['email'] . "|" .  $a['fname'] . "|" . $a['time'] . "|" . $time . "|" . $a['message'];
        }
      $b++;
      }
    echo $c;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Paul's answer. Some additions below.

1. Possible [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

   ```
   $email=$_SESSION['email'];
   $flname=$_SESSION['name'];
   $message=$this->_protected_arr['f4b'];
   $time=time();
   database::query("INSERT INTO tw VALUES ('$time','$flname','$message','$email')");
   ```

   If your `name` and `email` session variables are checked before you put them into the session and they could not contain any dangerous characters it's fine. If they could contain you should escape them. (Image a name with an `'`. It would broke the query.) Anyway, escaping is a good practice, it costs almost nothing and makes the code more reliable and safe. I would escape it.
2. I would rewrite the while loop if you stay with the original code instead of JSON:

   ```
   $first = true;
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return)) {  
       if (!$first) {
           $c .= "||";
       }
       $tw  = $row['email'] . "|";
       $tw .= $row['fname'] . "|";
       $tw .= $row['time'] . "|";
       $tw .= $time . "|";
       $tw .= tw_escape($row['message']);
       $c .= $tw;
       first = false;
   }
   ```

   The `$tw` variable removes some unnecessary code duplication. Changing the `$b` to a boolean (`$first`) makes is easier to read.
3. You should escape at least the `message` (that's the `tw_escape` function) in case a message contains `|`. Consider escaping the `$row['fname']` too. Don't forget to unescape on the client side. Maybe JSON does it out-of-the-box.

Comment: I'm setting the SESSION variables in my PHP script...therefore I do not have to worry about their contents?...or do I?...I only worry about data coming from the user...Is this correct...are SESSION variables an issue b.c. they might be saved on a cookie on the client side?

Comment: Wow...you are correct...the loop is messy...I will fix this.

Comment: I'm updatint | to <|> or similar to make it highly unique so I don't have to worry about escaping..nice catch.

Comment: and thank you for not telling me to use JSON

Comment: About the SQL injection: I would escape them. It does not hurt and it makes your code more reliable and safe.
 AFAIK session data in PHP stored on the server-side, so the clients are not able to modify it. You should escape (and unescape on the client-side) the `<|>` too. It solves the problem once for all.

Comment: Btw, what's the problem with JSON? :-)

Comment: @stack.user.0 JSON is the easiest way to pass data between PHP and Javascript.  All you have to do is call the function json_encode.  You won't get bugs with it like you could in your custom escaping code.  When you receive it in your javascript code it is already a native javascript object rather than a string that you have to regexp.  Tell me if you ever see the logic behind my advice, otherwise I give up.

Comment: all data comes in on packets...these packets have data...that can be thought of as an array of bits...these bits can be thought of as characters, these character can be thought of as a strings....the strings...can be shaped into structure data via a language called markup...b.c. I have the time I am writing my own markup...but yea...if you don't have a few hundred hours to kill I would go with JSON...it is obviously a standard that works well is well understood and there is huge amount of support for it...One day I will use JSON but I just want to learn this way..b.c. I have the time.

Comment: I have no prolem with JSON...I just want to learn the mechanics of markup...parsing....etc..on a lower level..hence writing my own markup and parsers

Answer (score 2):

So, this is the PHP that causes you to have your 'aml' processing [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5939/collection-of-ajax-methods).

I think people must have confused you by saying not to echo.  You are correct, you do have to communicate by printing something out.  The best way to communicate with Javascript is by using JSON.  JSON stands for JavaScript Object Notation.

You should also check for success or failure from the database query.  Below is untested code (I have no idea what your database::query returns so my error check may not be appropriate):

```
$query_return = database::query("SELECT * FROM tw ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7");

if ($query_return === false)
{
    echo json_encode(array('Success' => false));
    return;
}   

$results = array('Data'    => array(),
                 'Success' => true);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_return))
{  
    $results['Data'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($results);
```

So now you will receive an array of rows from your database that your javascript code can deal with nicely.  It will be a valid javascript object so you can check it with:

```
if (response.Success)
{
    // Do stuff with response.Data here.  Probably a loop over the results.
}
```

Comment: I've seen the code in `class database`.  The error check is fine; the query function is pretty much `return $db->query($sql);`, where `$db` is a mysqli object.